# Copy entire entity using EntityId in CQRS with eventSourcing

Tags: c#, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am using CQRS with event-sourcing. I have one entity eg.Form with entityId.  Now I have to send copy command(CommandName: CopyForm, EventName:FormCopied ) on this entity So, that entire Form should be copied and have different entityId.

So, to achieve this I am sending entityId of form with CopyForm command which need to be copied. Entire form is loaded from event-store  and while raising event I am raising event as FormAdded instead of FormCopied which will add new form exactly same as source form which we are loading from eventStore and just setting new entityId . But issue here it is raising event for same form which I am copying instead of copied form. My framework doesn't allow to change entityId. Framework by default set entityId of command which I am raising for source Form and event is raised for source Form with same entityId.

Is there any better way of doing Copy functionality for entity in CQRS with Event-Sourcing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan's answer is good, but a little bit incomplete.

In an event sourcing system, the domain's command service needs to be able to rehydrate entities from the event log.  Whatever the backing store of the event log, it will likely be indexed by EntityID and Entities will be rehydrated by pulling all events for the given EntityID from the backing data storage. Hence, the FormCopied event will need to have a standard EntityId field, will it not?

We could use the following:

```
FormCopied { EntityId, OriginalEntityId }
```

This is only slightly different from Bryan's answer, in that it allows for an Event Store that's indexed by EntityId.

It seems correct that the FormCopied event would be part of the stream that will rehydrate the new "Form" entity.  But there are still problems. For example, imagine that next our user tries to add a new field to his/her form.  Here is a likely next command:

```
AddFieldToForm { EntityId, NewField }
```

Now, Imagine also that this "Form" Entity has some business rules to check, as Entities often do.  The command service will want to load up the new "Form" entity in order check the business rules, so it will try to rehydrate The "Form" entity from the event log.  We pull the event log and find only one event.

```
FormCopied { EntityId, OriginalEntityId }
```

So now we have to go back to the event log and also pull the event stream for the OriginalEntityId in order to get a fully rehydrated copy of the new entity.  There are at least 2 ways you might do this:

1. By actually pulling the event stream for OriginalEntityId and then replaying it as if it's events were originated from this new entity - or -
2. By loading up the original entity that corresponds with OriginalEntityId and copying it's properties one by one over to the new entity.

Which you choose would depend on the capabilities of your framework.

Comment: What if we are raising event as FormAdded instead of FormCopied? Why do we still need not to raise each event separately which occurred previously  for original entity ?

Answer (score 4):

Publish an event stating the new fact:

```
FormCopied { OriginalEntityId, NewEntityId }
```

Combined with the domain's history, you now have enough information to know exactly what the copy should contain, as well as the relationship of the two entities (with ids).

Comment: The version of the original entity should also be included :o)

Comment: @SirRufo: The `FormCopied` event tells us the point in time the original was copied, giving us exactly enough information to go on without introducing extra data. Event sourcing is great because you get to take advantage of temporal relationships, something often lost in n-tier systems.

Answer (score 1):

Your case seems a bit strange but anyway, the simplest method I can think of is to get the events stream of the Form, duplicate them and replace the entity Id in the copies (you can do that because events are simple data structures). Then save and publish the new event stream. If the fact that is copied has domain significance, the FormAdded event can have a property `IsCopied`.